# Install rtl8192cu WLAN driver on android

Tags: pi-2, wifi, usb, driver, android

I have a RPi2 and have installed Lineage OS 14.1 (Android 7.1.2)

However my wifi adapter(`0bda:8176 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188CUS 802.11n WLAN Adapter`) which worked on Raspbian, doesn't seem to work on Android.

After doing a bit of research I found out that `0bda:8176` uses the `rtl8192cu` driver, but I haven't been able to install it.

How do I install this?

UPDATE: I think that I will have to build the driver from source, however I don't think there is a copy of the kernel headers available online.

Is there anyway to extract the kernel headers from the OS?